# Format a HEX string as byte array after "leave" the textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I've made a little application using windows forms where I can enter a hexadecimal number and convert it to decimal number, but I don't know how to format the text from the textbox automatically when I click outside of the textbox, I've searched over the internet and foud that "OnLeave" actions is what I need.
When I said format the text I refer to this:

```
Value 1: 0x00aa00bb -> 0x 00 aa 00 bb
Value 2: 45aa00CC -> 45 aa 00 cc
```

Just format them like I have a byte array because I want to use this to also convert hexadecimal to float, and this way is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple "for-loop" to parse the value you've enter, on every iteration select 2 characters and append a whitespace after them:

```
private void txtHexadecimal_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String value = txtHexadecimal.Text;
            value = value.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
            if (value.Length % 2 == 0)
            {
                String output = "";
                int spliceValue_B = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < value.Length / 2; i++)
                {
                    String sp = value.Substring(spliceValue_B, 2);
                    if (i != (value.Length / 2) - 1)
                        sp += " ";
                    output += sp;
                    spliceValue_B += 2;
                }

                txtHexadecimal.Text = output;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, works like charm! I also should delete the last whitespace before I display the modified. text.

Comment: you should use Trim() function: txtHexadecimal.Text = output.Trim();

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, just because this is my favorite Monday so far this week:

```
private void txtHexadecimal_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool addSpaceBefore = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(char c in txtHexadecimal.Text.Where(x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x))) {
        if (addSpaceBefore && sb.Length>0)
        {
            sb.Append(' ');
        }
        sb.Append(c);
        addSpaceBefore = !addSpaceBefore;
    }
    txtHexadecimal.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```